# operator does not exist: bigint = uuid LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "users" ON

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I decided to change my default id today because I thought of scalability of my project. Since I changed the user main primary key to UUID I ran into a series of errors, some of which I could fix thanks to some questions on stackoverflow.

I'm using the "oauth2_provider_access token" for my authentication from the [oauth2_provider](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

I don't really know again from where this other one came from but when ever I try my API I'm stuck.

My error log below

```bash
[08/Feb/2023 08:46:54] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: bigint = uuid
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "users" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "users"....
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
.
.
.
.
.
.
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user_me/f_project/softwareAPI/software_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: bigint = uuid
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "users" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "users"....
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[08/Feb/2023 08:46:54] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 449397
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Feb/2023 08:46:54] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2986
```

Can anyone be of help please?

In case of any other detail, please comment.

I expected successful work of the /login and /register APIs, but got the error above.

Comment: "django_admin_log"."user_id" is still a bigint, not a UUID

Comment: Where can I change that?